# Does AngularJS offer advantages for a simple AJAX website

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs

I have made a simple site which I now want to add a javascript overlay to do some relatively simple things such as:

- Make the search box and pagination ajax driven to results can be loaded in without a refresh
- Integrate the HTML5 history system
- Add form validation

My coder has told me that I should use angular over jquery. When I look into it, it seems Angular is designed for large, completely AJAX driven sites, and ends up using jquery or jquery lite anyway.

My question is, does angular offer any significant advantages for my use case, to counteract the disadvantage of the learning curve and lack of community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion there is no point for you to get hands dirty with AngularjJS for one small and rather simple project.
If you plan to extend your website in near future and continuously add new features than it is something to consider along many other options.

Answer (score 0):

The beauty of AngularJS from what I've seen so far is that it's easy enough to drop into any project regardless of size. I've made a simple application like you described and it was still faster than just avoiding it all together.

Answer (score 0):

We have been using Angularjs and saw that it saves much time of us in comparision with jQuery.

Angularjs uses Declarative programming for processing UI. It means that you only

need to declare your UI logic, Angularjs will process it for you.

See this link please: [ANGULAR PHILOSOPHY](http://jshtml5.stest.dotohsoft.com/#/44)

Now we still use jQuery in some cases but Angularjs is our top priority.

I advice you to learn and use it now.